# Getting SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3 Error writing file '/tmp/MYgahdeW' (Errcode: 28) error while searching products

Tags: catalogsearch, sql

I am getting following error while searching products.

```
Getting SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3 Error writing file '/tmp/MYgahdeW' (Errcode: 28) error while searching products
```

Trace:

```
#0 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `_oc_o`....', Array)
#4 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `_oc_o`....', Array)
#5 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Resource/Filter/Attribute.php(93): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Model/Filter/Attribute.php(229): Mana_Filters_Resource_Filter_Attribute->optimizedCountOnCollection(Object(Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Collection), Object(Mana_Filters_Model_Filter_Attribute), Array)
#8 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Model/Query.php(230): Mana_Filters_Model_Filter_Attribute->optimizedCountOnCollection(Object(Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Collection), Array)
#9 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Model/Filter/Attribute.php(74): Mana_Filters_Model_Query->getAllOptimizedAttributeFilterCounts()
#10 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Model/Filter/Attribute.php(290): Mana_Filters_Model_Filter_Attribute->_getItemsData()
#11 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(120): Mana_Filters_Model_Filter_Attribute->_initItems()
#12 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(109): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItems()
#13 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Block/Filter.php(84): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#14 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/design/frontend/default/theme375/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml(49): Mana_Filters_Block_Filter->getItemsCount()
#15 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/cpanelusername/...')
#16 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#17 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#21 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#23 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/design/frontend/default/theme375/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#24 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/cpanelusername/...')
#25 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#26 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#27 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#30 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php(80): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#31 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController->indexAction()
#32 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#33 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#34 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#35 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#36 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#37 {main}
```

The error occurs often and the /tmp mount point goes to 100% from 3%. I did contacted the hosting support team and they said it is something to do with the Magento.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that tmp disk is full. Magento uses MySQL to store it data and MySQL uses tmp catalog quite extensively.

Unfortunately I don't know how big your tmp category mount point is and what action you've tried to perform. I have also no idea about the size of your database. You could check out MySQL Query Execution plan, you could clean up your database (more data means bigger temporary files, obviously).

And yeah, it has something to do with Magento (since you were so inconsiderate to actually run it) -- those lazy support people didn't bother to check what out what's really is going on. They always sort of expect people just to store stuff on their hard disks and not actually execute any code.

TL;DR you need more space!

Comment: /tmp mount point size is 485M and the database size is 4945.10 MB. I have tried repairing and optimizing the database but it is not helping at all.

Comment: I'm shooting from the hip here, but there're two things I would try out: a) more disk space as mysql temporary files can easily pass 100MB and b) play around with MySQL config file. It could be that you have buffers bigger than available space in /tmp folder.

Comment: There's actually one other option - you ran out of iNodes

Comment: Errcode: 28 is an OS error defined in the linux OS `#define ENOSPC  28  /* No space left on device */` and if you have a cheap hosting service, they probably didn't define http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html `file-per-table` mode, so no amount of optimization will shrink the innodb database storage file.

Comment: The Mana_Filters module is probably running a query with a very inefficient query like SELECT * FROM t1, t2; where t1 and t2 have a lot of rows. It probably works fine with a small database but the tmp table size grows exponentially and therefore fails with a bigger one. Use MySQL general log to find the bad query and rewrite it to be more efficient.